# Alternate to table to display data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a table in HTML but it seems the table is unable to meet the specs.  I would like to data to be in the same place on the screen otherwise it will cause all kinds of problems with the users as they mis-read the data.  So I need fixed width columns.  I also would like the column headers to remian fixed if the data exceeds the height of the windows because some users do use them.

I do not want to install any 3rd party controls if possible.  The owner will not buy anything anyway.  I don't mind something that downloads with the page.

I was thinking of trying to make a scrollable div with textboxes or labels but thought I should check to see if someone has already run into this issue and came up with a solution.

I asked here: [How to make a scrolling table with dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055446/how-to-make-a-scrolling-table-with-dynamic-data)
but no one has a clue as to whats wrong.

Then I asked here: [How to get a table to fit its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080751/how-to-get-a-table-to-fit-its-parent-container)
And the key here seems the column widths.  But without the widths using the table seems pointless.

Asking this: [Why don't my column headings line up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079111/why-dont-my-column-headings-line-up)
Seems also to indicate that a table will never work.
Setting this:

```
display: table-row-group
```

Makes the column headings line up, but then the table can not scroll.

```
display: block
```

Makes the table scroll but the column headings are wrong.

Here's an example that works on its own.  http://jsfiddle.net/kjzcv9g2/

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
table, th, td {border: solid;}

thead {
display: block;
color: #f00;
background: #eee;
height: 35px; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
}

tbody {
display: block;
height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

th, td {
width: 10em; 
font-weight: normal; 
}
</style>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>foo</th>
<th>bar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>bar</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But getting this to work seems impossible.

Any suggestions on whether to use labels or textboxes to create my own table?

Comment: I think all of the issues pointed out in your question are exactly why a lot of people lean toward 3rd party tools.  To correct some/all of those potential issues can take a ***lot*** of code.  The big hook of the 3rd party tools are they take care of all that crazy math, CSS, and javascript for you :P

Comment: lot of code huh?  Good thing I am a coder.  I excel at producing a lot of code.  Plus I can boast that after numerous postings at numerous forums there was no one in the world that could come up with a solution, but I did!!

Comment: Having a hard time following your question: You want the column headers to align to the columns in fixed width or you want the table to span it's encompassing container? 
Normally, assigning `table-layout: fixed;` to your table should suffice. Would you mind updating your fiddle to a broken state and telling us what you want to fix?

Comment: By your response it makes me wonder if what I want to do is impossible.  I will claify.  I would like the table to be able to shrink and grow to fill the container.  I also want fixed column widths.  If the container is smaller than the table with fixed column widths I would like the table to be scrollable but I would also like the headers to remain.  Here is a broken fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3g26nx8/1/  Here is another broken one http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/1/  Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kjzcv9g2/5/)

If I understand the question correctly the above should work. Add a `min-width` to the overall table and you'll have fixed width columns below the min width, and the columns will fill the container about the min width.